# Asian appearance, look or face?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I want to express the meaning that I look like a typical East Asian. Can I say that:

1) I have a (typical) Asian (physical) appearance?
2) I have an Asian look?
3) I have an Asian face?

Or any alternatives to introducing one's ethnicity?

Comment: An Asian appearance is a neutral way of expressing what you want to say, bearing in mind that Asia is a vast continent whose peoples exhibit a great variety of facial features.

Comment: @RonaldSole Oh, yes. Maybe better to be more specific. But I thought it would be abnormal to say An East Asian.

Comment: At least in Canada, "East Asian" is commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "appearance" could include the way you dress, not specifically your face.

Leaving aside any thoughts on whether it is okay to say "Asian" (as I believe some people find it a little non-specific and therefore a generalisation) I would suggest saying:

> I have typically Asian *features*.

Comment: In this context, in Britain, "Asian" means "South Asian". Maybe we aren't as PC as Americans, but you can safely say "Chinese" here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I think more people are offended by the term "oriental". Being white myself I didn't want to comment but would have felt amiss not mentioning it whilst advising someone to say "Asian". Asia covers a large area though, and I'm sure that someone from Thailand does not have identical features to someone from China. It seems a generalisation, but definitely a discussion for another forum. ;)

Comment: @Astralbee OK. The context is: I was telling a German a story of mine and just used "appearance" but felt I was wrong later. So it doesn't matter for an European to differentiate between Sourth Asian and Chinese in this case. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [countenance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/countenance), which means "the appearance or expression of someone's face."

You can say, "I am of Asian countenance."